# Failed to run or preview report in SSRS and SQL Server Report Builder

Tags: ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I have a couple reports I inherited that needed updating to our new database structure. I have those changes done, but when I try to preview two of the reports using SQL Server Report Builder 3.0 it gives me the following error message:

> Failed to preview report
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Error while loading code module: ‘ReportLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null’. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'ReportLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010Impl.CreateReportEditSession(String Report, String Parent, Byte[] Definition, String& EditSessionID, Warning[]& Warnings)
>      at Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.CreateReportEditSession(String Report, String Parent, Byte[] Definition, String& EditSessionID, Warning[]& Warnings)

The other reports that I have already fixed work perfectly fine when previewing. This same error also shows up when I try to upload it to the Report Server. All of this is running off my Windows 7 x64 machine.

I'm thinking that this report is corrupted, but I don't want to have to rebuild it from scratch if that isn't the case. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this error a few times and it's so annoying but I am going to say I spent hours searching the web because I didn't want to recreate the report.
But in the end found nothing and had to recreate the report anyway.

Don't waste your time looking for a fix it is corrupt.

Comment: Thanks. I was figuring that would most likely be the case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with the header (and thus the namespace). Create or look at a working report, then compare the header (which indicates the XML version). If they are different, replace the header from the report that doesn't work with the one that works.